# function dispose mootools.floor not work

Tags: javascript, mootools, floor

I want to use this validate form

http://mootools.floor.ch/en/download/

but don't work.

```
    <form name="niceform" id="third" action=""  class="niceform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="titlu_form"> categoría: </div> 
     <div class="option_form"> 
     <select name="categorie" id="categorie" class="validate['required']">
      <option value=""> -- Elige categoría -- </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
      <option value="3"> 3 </option>
     </select>
    </div>

   <div class="titlu_form"> provincia: </div> 
    <div class="option_form"> 
     <select name="provincia" class="validate['required']">
      <option value=""> -- Provincia -- </option>
      <option value="Castellon"> Castellon </option>
      <option value="Valencia"> Valencia </option>
     </select>    
    </div>`

   <div class="titlu_form"> marca: </div> 
    <div class="option_form"> 
     <select name="marca12" id="marca" class="validate['required']">
      <option value=""> -- Marca -- </option>
      <option value="jeans"> jeans </option>
      <option value="other"> other </option>
     </select>  
    </div>

   <input type="submit" name="Submit" />   
  </form>
```

this is the script i use for validate

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightform/mootools.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lightform/formcheck.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  //h
  window.addEvent('domready', function(){     
   formcheck = new FormCheck('third', {
     display : {
                 fadeDuration : 500,
                 errorsLocation : 1,
                 indicateErrors : 1,
                 showErrors : 1
             }
         })
   //$('marca').removeAttribute('class');
   formcheck.dispose($('marca'));
  });

  //and this is opcionaly for a select option 
   $('categorie').addEvent('change', function(event){
       var selection = document.getElementById('categorie').value;
       alert(selection);
       if(selection==1) { 
        alert(selection);
        formcheck.dispose($('marca'));
        $('marca').removeAttribute('class');
       }
 });

</script>
```

result this error:

```
formcheck.dispose is not defined.
```

I want to hide div marca when select a option 2 or 3 .. that is..
how about this ..

Comment: this looks like it got copied straight from the [docs / examples](http://mootools.floor.ch/docs/formcheck/files/formcheck-js.html#FormCheck.dispose) page. is it literally what you run? is `formcheck` itself defined or is this a scope error?

Comment: what version of mootools are you running?

Comment: I used mootools 1.11 and 1.4.5 (not at the same time).

Comment: I use a different formcheck.js    Link to download :  http://darabani.net/fisiere/formcheck.js

Comment: so what's the output of `console.log(this.formcheck)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you stated that you tried it in moo 1.11 and 1.45

that is your issue. It was written for 1.2.x

I ported this to 1.4.x awhile ago use the below code base and your problem will go away

http://www.timwickstrom.com/client-side-code/mootools/moofloor-formcheck-for-mootools-1-4-x/